# text overlapping in mobile view html css - tried solutions from other queries to no avail

Tags: html, css, mobile, overlap, divide

The website looks fine in on my laptop but when I check it on my phone these three texts overlap. I tried responsive line breaks using span and adding @media to css -based on some similar but not identical questions by other users - however the overlap remained. Any suggestions? Here is the code that pertains without any of the attempted changes.

Edit: As an experiment I changed the one of the texts to a very large font which caused the large font text to overlap the other two on my laptop. I am knew to coding clearly but this makes me think it's an issue with my decision to use div? Help!
Edit: here is the full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Great+Vibes&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Meddon&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<style>



body  {
  background-color:#E6D3A3;
}

h1 {text-align: center;  font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;}

ul {
width: 100%
text-align: center;
display: inline block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: gray;
}

div {
-webkit-background-size: contain no-repeat;
-moz-background-size: contain no-repeat;
-o-background-size: contain no-repeat;
background-size: contain no-repeat;
}


 .center {
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  font-family: 'Meddon', cursive;
  font-size: 30px;


}
.center p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;

}

.paragraph {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;

}
.paragraph p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 30%;
  transform: translate(-20%, -20%);
  margin: 0; }

#footer{
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}


</style>


<title> Home </title>


</head>


 <body>
 
<h1 style="font-size:90px"> home page</h1>

<ul> 
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news"> Tours</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">About Shirley</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">Contact & Web links</a></li>
</ul>


 
 

<img src="mont.jpg" width="337" height="210">
<img src="ro.jpg" width="337" height="210" >
<img src="mo.jpg" width="338" height="210" >

<div class="center">
 <p> more text here</p>  </div> 

 <div class="paragraph">
 <p> Step back in time with Shirley Midyette more text etc etc long paragraphStep back in time with Shirley Midyette more text etc etc long paragraph Step back in time with Shirley Midyette more text etc etc long paragraph Step back in time with Shirley Midyette more text etc etc long paragraph Step back in time with Shirley Midyette more text etc etc long paragraph Step back in time with Shirley Midyette more text etc etc long paragraph Step back in time with Shirley Midyette more text etc etc long paragraph Step back in time with Shirley Midyette more text etc etc long paragraph Step back in time with Shirley Midyette more text etc etc long paragraph Step back in time with Shirley Midyette more text etc etc long paragraph Step back in time with Shirley Midyette more text etc etc long paragraph <a style="font-weight:bold" href="inserthere.html"</a>
 </p> </div> 
 
 <div id="footer">
   <p>Copyright &copy; 2021 my website LLC. All rights reserved</p> </div>

  </body>
 
 </html>
```

Comment: Not able to reproduce your problem with the given code. Kindly provide the full code.

Comment: Thanks  very much for your comment - I provided the code for the full page.

Answer (score 0):

Your overlapping happens due to absolute positioning. You should treat it as a block element.

```css
body {
  background-color: #e6d3a3;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Great Vibes", cursive;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: gray;
}

div {
  -webkit-background-size: contain no-repeat;
  -moz-background-size: contain no-repeat;
  -o-background-size: contain no-repeat;
  background-size: contain no-repeat;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Meddon", cursive;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.paragraph {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

#footer {
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="font-size:90px"> home page</h1>

<ul> 
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news"> Tours</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">About Shirley</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">Contact & Web links</a></li>
</ul>


 
 

<img src="mont.jpg" width="337" height="210">
<img src="ro.jpg" width="337" height="210" >
<img src="mo.jpg" width="338" height="210" >

<div class="center">
 <p> more text here</p>  </div> 

 <div class="paragraph">
 <p> Step back in time with Shirley Midyette more text etc etc long paragraphStep back in time with Shirley Midyette more text etc etc long paragraph Step back in time with Shirley Midyette more text etc etc long paragraph Step back in time with Shirley Midyette more text etc etc long paragraph Step back in time with Shirley Midyette more text etc etc long paragraph Step back in time with Shirley Midyette more text etc etc long paragraph Step back in time with Shirley Midyette more text etc etc long paragraph Step back in time with Shirley Midyette more text etc etc long paragraph Step back in time with Shirley Midyette more text etc etc long paragraph Step back in time with Shirley Midyette more text etc etc long paragraph Step back in time with Shirley Midyette more text etc etc long paragraph <a style="font-weight:bold" href="inserthere.html"</a>
 </p> </div> 
 
 <div id="footer">
   <p>Copyright &copy; 2021 my website LLC. All rights reserved</p> </div>
```